# What's wrong with the following code block?

Tags: c

Why does the following code block not work?

```
int *p1 = malloc(128);

int main(void) {
char *p2 = malloc(128);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you paste in the error message?

Comment: (1): error: Initializer must be constant.

Comment: Define “does not work”: what errors do you get, what did you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: @asafreedman void in main is very correct, even more than without.

Comment: Because it's not legal C syntax.

Answer (score 2):

initializer of a global variable must be constant, so the first `malloc` will cause a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use malloc to initialize p1 outside of the a code block like that, just do it inside main like p2

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a function in the initialization of a global variable. This is the line it's complaining about:

```
int *p1 = malloc(128);
```

Change this to NULL and then in main, initialize it.

Answer (score -2):

1st, the basic error is that your main method must return some int value

```
int main(void) {
char *p2 = malloc(128);
return 0;
}
```

or try

```
void main(){
char *p2 = malloc(128);
}
```

2nd, you may want to specify what kind of buffer that your pointer is, otherwise, it will be a (void*) type pointer, so I suggest that you can try:

```
int *p1 = (int*)malloc(128);
char *p2 = (char*)malloc(128);
```

Comment: -1 `void main()` is really not correct. Also casting a malloc is not necessary. Void pointer is automagically converted to any pointer, you don't have to specify anything.

Comment: I would put it much more strongly than that: `void main()` is wrong on any hosted implementation, resulting in Undefined Behavior. Never do that.